# Get manually opened firefox window with Selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

As I was working on my Selenium project, I wondered if it was possible to link my project to an already existing firefox window, opened by hand, so not controlled by the marionette.

I defined a `browser` as a `selenium.Firefox()`, and tried to print the `browser.window_handles`, but it only returned me the window opened by selenium.

Is there any way to connect to an already existing window ? It would be useful, for example, for a password manager if you don't want to store your logins into your browser, as it is not safe...